# Python 3.5 SMTP library

Tags: python-3.x, smtp, windows-7-x64

I need connect my python code to my SMTP Azure server to retrieve some emails, I was checking the documentation of imaplib and I can connetc without problem to my gmail account but I can't to my azure one!

Does someone of you know how to connect to Azure with python?

Do you have an example of code to connect and retrieve all the email of today?

Thanks so so much :D

Comment: Are not you confusing SNMP with SMTP? The latter deals with e-mails, while the former is not. If you need to download email from IMAP server, take a look at `imaplib` (shipped with Python).

Comment: Hi @IlyaEtingof Thanks so much for your help, yes was SMTP, I used the library that you advice me but I have the same some problem, I use a code found in internet and it's working for my gmail but not for connect to my azure email service :( so probably need some extra information/configuration! I'm going to edit my question with the new details ;) thanks so much for your help :D

Comment: pls see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719275/python-3-5-smtp-and-imaplib-with-microsoft-azure-email-service